# OR and index creation

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing

I use SQL Azure and try to create nonclustered index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SyncNotNull ON  MyTable 
    (IMEI, Sync1, Sync2, FieldA, FieldB, FieldC)  
    WHERE (Sync1 = 1 OR Sync2 = 1);
```

But I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

I google and found, that no possible to use `OR` for index `WHERE` condition, but how to replace it?

I tried

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SyncNotNull ON  Device 
    (IMEI, Id, Name, DeviceModelId, Status, SyncVerizon, SyncSureMdm, CarrierId, LastConnectionDate)  
    WHERE (1 in (SyncVerizon, SyncSureMdm));
```

but it's also incorrect statement

**ADDED**

Found solution like:

```
WHERE CAST(SyncSureMdm AS INT) + CAST([SyncVerizon] AS INT) > 0
```

but will be this effectively, with type conversion?

Comment: Create two indexes, one for each condition. I'm not familiar with Azure, maybe `COALESCE` would work, but I doubt it

Comment: Which Azure product are you using, you don't say. That syntax is permitted in S
Azure SQL Databases.

Comment: @HoneyBadger sorry, my prev example had an error, really I have bit fields, not nullable. So, COALESCE is not appropriated. But thank you anyway

Comment: @Larnu I use Azure SQL Database

Comment: how about WHERE `SyncVerizon + SyncSureMdm > 0`

Comment: @topsail SQL Server disallows anything like that in a filtered index. [Check the syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax): you can only use `column comparison_op value` or `column IN (value, value...)`

Comment: @topsail thanks for response, but for bit fields + operator can't be used :)

Comment: @topsail found with `CAST` solution, based on your idea, but will be this effectively?

Comment: The indexed view idea below looks promising. I'm discovering that filtered indexes are somewhat limited in how complex the filter conditions can be - but you can try to whittle out the meaning from the documents if you want (or just try it -- easier): [check the syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax)

Comment: You could also go back to square one (see first comment) and create two separate indexes, one for each sync column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such expressions are [disallowed by the syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax) for filtered index.

You could instead create an indexed view, which will behave much like a filtered index, although they do have some restrictions, primarily in your case that they need to be schema-bound.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.View_SyncNotNull
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
  t.IMEI,
  t.Sync1,
  t.Sync2,
  t.FieldA,
  t.FieldB,
  t.FieldC
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE (t.Sync1 = 1 OR t.Sync2 = 1);
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_SyncNotNull ON View_SyncNotNull
    (Id);
```

Choose your unique clustering key carefully: in your case it should probably be the primary key of the base table. All other columns in the view will be included automatically, like any other clustered index.

If you are not using Enterprise/Developer Edition, you should modify relevant queries to access this view directly, using the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint. And even on Enterprise Edition [this is worthwhile](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints).

Comment: why did you add only one field (Id) to index instead of all necessary?

Comment: Because it's a **clustered** index so automatically adds all other columns in the view

Comment: Oh, sorry, lost this moment